# How do I turn off the map POI data using googlemaps in gmaps4rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, gmaps4rails

I have been using google maps for a web app where we enter our own custom location data for markers, and have been noticing that in higher zoom settings, the google maps data shines through, literally taking away the whole point of having custom map data.

I am using gmaps4rails, and have the gmaps JSON code, from the Google Maps API v3 Styled Maps JSON editor, and cannot get the right callback area for this.

Any ideas where I should be placing this? The callback is not allowing for this to work. (and I suck at JS)

Thanks!

Comment: I'd need more details to understand your issue.

Comment: Trying to implement custom Google Maps API v3 Styled Maps JSON options to make the skin of every map the same, making a 'custom colored' map. Right now, inserting through a callback and passing options is not working, and I wonder if that is the best way to specify these changes- http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html - using this JSON for the map skin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I took an example from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html). Just do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
var pinkParksStyles = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -80 }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "poi.park",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#ff0023" },
      { saturation: 40 }
    ]
   }
  ];

  Gmaps.map.map.setOptions({styles: pinkParksStyles});
}
</script>
```

Another solution instead of using the callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var pinkParksStyles = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -80 }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "poi.park",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#ff0023" },
      { saturation: 40 }
    ]
  }
];
</script>

<%= gmaps(:map_options => { :raw => "{styles: pinkParksStyles}" },
          #... whatever you need
    )
%>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was missing out on the 'Gmaps.map.map.setOptions({styles: pinkParkStyles}); Thanks for reminding my noob self!

Comment: I definitely hate my dumb syntax: `Gmaps.map.map` but I don't know how to deprecate smoothly

Comment: Shouldn't this be done outside of callback? Now that I read the functionality of the callback from the wiki, it seems that it loads after map and items are created. To skin the map, one would think the code needs to be in the 'creating' stage?

Comment: Also, with the above setup as-is, it is not skinning at all

Comment: Callback is the way to do with the gem, or maybe use the 'raw' option you can pass to the gmaps helper. I made it work with the code above, so what's your error?

Comment: You know what it was? I had refactored a separate callback and then inserted this into my application.erb, I combined the two and we're golden. Thanks for making me think! Cheers

Comment: I forgot to edit the wiki with this useful config option, now it's properly documented there.